# Ruby-on-rails form_for div or span method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, html, form-for

Is there any method to use beneath form_for that creates a div or span tag that will be inserted into the database? Something like:

```
<%= form_for @object do |f| %>
  <%= f.div_field :column %>
<% end %>
```

The reason for this is I have several javascript functions that update the content within the div tag and I want the content to get stored in a table in my database. Is this possible, or do I need to just use text inputs with uneditable content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know about that, but you could always use f.hidden_field :column.  In your javascript, when you update the content of the div, also update the content of the hidden field.  That way, you can still submit your form and get the content to the server without having to expose a text field.

Perhaps you could also style the immutable text area such that it looks less like a text area; hide the scrollbars and borders and it may look just like a div.  But if you want a real div, I would go the hidden field route.

Comment: Oh carp, how did I not think of that? I'm even using hidden fields to accomplish nearly the same thing somewhere else in my app. Thanks a lot, mate. Ye've been a big help. May your sword stay sharp and your steed be quick.